# Como deixar um AlertDialog com bordas arredondadas?

Tags: java, android

Quando quero fazer um `Dialog` personalizado eu apenas coloco um *layout* dentro dele. Mas em volta no `Dialog` fica quadrado, alguém sabe como arredondar?

Answer (score 3):

Segue um exemplo:

**Java**:

```
Dialog  dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

**dialog_layout.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_box"
    android:layout_gravity="center”>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**drawable/rounded_box.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color=“#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius=“5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que alterar o tema possa te ajudar, só que será necessário configurar manualmente algumas informações de tamanho do seu alertDialog, arrume um layout para ser a base no seu xml, e dentro dele centralize o que você quer no tamanho que deseja, e no seu código onde você cria o Builder do alertDialog o tema como parâmetro:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Note que isso deixará seu alert dialog transparente, para deixar os cantos arredondados basta você colocar uma imagem com cantos arredondados e que tenha transparência e por fim definir como background do seu layout.